# Can we get a Lightbox (click to enlarge) for images?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images

I always have to right-click and open a new tab to see an image in it's full resolution. Since we are a gaming site, screenshots are quite common and often used.

I would really like if the developers could give us a light-box that can enlarge the images linked inside the browser. There are plenty of free implementations on the web, so this would be a minimal effort to include it into Stack Exchange.

Comment: +1 because I had this problem recently when I had to use a very wide image in this answer: [How to build a enchanting table](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/179198/how-to-build-a-enchanting-table/179234#179234)

Comment: Consider using the [Imagus](https://97e572bee9692acbd88571f49c074e24ffd9c03b.googledrive.com/host/0Bx8fnUCX4W2IUTNPT0s2eUFDQms/) extension.

Answer (score 5):

No need to use frankly annoying lightboxes when good old Markdown would do:

```
[![Alt-text][1]][1]

[(Click to embiggen)][1]

   [1]: http://whatever/
```

This markdown is now generated by default when uploading an image using the image tool.

Comment: this is now the default behavior when using the image uploader